# how to deal with time series data for svm multi-class classification problem

Tags: time-series, svm

I am more used to data sets that looks like the breast cancer data set and iris flower data set, and am very unfamiliar with time series data sets.

The problem is to classify signals according to the output signal given a unique signal pattern over a period of time. How do I go about in labelling the data and proceed with training and classification?

given that the data looks like the following,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
    time&signal\\  \hline
0.0010&0.002292\\  
   \hline
0.0020&0.004544\\  \hline
0.0030&0.004752\\ \hline
0.0040&0.004912\\ \hline
0.0050&0.004534\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: What is your classification about? What are you trying to predict?

Comment: There are several unique signal patterns under certain different conditions in an electrical system. I am trying to classify these different conditions in real time.

Comment: Well, you need to work on the signal in order to create your target (the patterns you want to classify) in your training data. Then you can create features as lagged differences of your signal, or rolling averages and variances over a given window.

Comment: does that mean that the data will require zero padding and look like the following, given that the window is 0.0030 seconds long, $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    time&signal features&class\\  \hline
0.0010&[0.002292, 0, 0]&0\\  
   \hline
0.0020&[0.004544, 0.002292, 0]&0\\  \hline
0.0030&[0.004752, 0.004544, 0.002292]&1\\ \hline
0.0040&[0.004912, 0.004752, 0.004544]&2\\ \hline
0.0050&[0.004534, 0.004912, 0.004752]&3\\ \hline
\end{array}$$